# Collecting distinct key value-pairs of Nested type in ClickHouse into arrays

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have data with the following schema in ClickHouse:

```
CREATE TABLE table AS (
     key String,
     …
     nested Nested (
            key String,
            value String
     )
) …
```

Some example data:

```
key | … | nested                        |
----|---|-------------------------------|
k1  |   | [{"key": "a", "value": "1"}]  |
k1  |   | [{"key": "a", "value": "2"}]  |
k1  |   | [{"key": "a", "value": "1"},  |
    |   |   "key": "a", "value": "2"}]  |
k1  |   | [{"key": "b", "value": "3"    |
```

I want to group by the key and collect all the distinct key-value pairs into two arrays:

```
key   |  nested.key     |  nested.value    |
------|-----------------|------------------|
k1    | ["a", "a", "b"] |  ["1", "2", "3"] |
```

What is the simplest and most efficient way to do this in ClickHouse?

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest this query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    key,
    arrayDistinct(groupArray((nested.key, nested.value))) AS distinctNested,
    arrayMap(x -> (x.1), distinctNested) AS `nested.keys`,
    arrayMap(x -> (x.2), distinctNested) AS `nested.values`
FROM test.table_002
ARRAY JOIN nested
GROUP BY key

/* Result
┌─key─┬─distinctNested──────────────────┬─nested.keys───┬─nested.values─┐
│ k1  │ [('a','1'),('a','2'),('b','3')] │ ['a','a','b'] │ ['1','2','3'] │
└─────┴─────────────────────────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────┘
*/

/* Test data preparing */

CREATE TABLE test.table_002 (
  key String,
  nested Nested (key String, value String)
) ENGINE = Memory;

INSERT INTO test.table_002
FORMAT JSONEachRow
{"key": "k1", "nested.key":["a"], "nested.value": ["1"]}
{"key": "k1", "nested.key":["a"], "nested.value": ["2"]}
{"key": "k1", "nested.key":["a", "a"], "nested.value": ["1", "2"]}
{"key": "k1", "nested.key":["b"], "nested.value": ["3"]}
```

Comment: The problem with unnesting like this is that it will complicate aggregations on other columns.